# Terminal emulation has stopped working. Garbage escape chars

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, iphone

To enable me to do some remote administration of our servers I started using a terminal emulation program called TouchTerm Pro on my iPhone. While not the smoothest experience, it has allowed me to leave my computer behind when going out of town, which makes the slightly painful experience worthwhile.

As of late, the app unfortunately no longer works. Pressing up and down keys after logging on via ssh gives me garbage like ^[[A and ^[[B. Combinations with Ctrl - like you can see in the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHOP-sEa2bc) - no longer works either. Writing full command lines and executing by the enter key works though. Being able to search my bash history was the difference between a usable app and endless frustration, so getting it to work is essential. The app has (of course) met its end of life, not getting updated anymore.

I am not quite sure, which side (client or server) that has to be "fixed"/hacked to make the control sequences work again. But is there something I can do to make it work as intended? Maybe force some kind of VT100 emulation or something (I have no clue about terminal standards).

You can see a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHOP-sEa2bc) of TouchTerm in operation here.

Comment: Has it stopped working locally or when connected through ssh? Purging possible configurations might be an option.

Comment: It is after logging in to the server.

Comment: And it's not a problem on the server side?

Comment: Well, I have not changed anything, and I log in via OS X or Windows every day by ssh. I have just created a new session to a server that I have never used before, and the problem is the same. Arrow keys, control, etc. all show as escape sequences.

Comment: My best guess would to dig through the options and see if something is spooky there.

Comment: This is a new iPhone. My last one was stolen six months ago. So I have just restored the previous one. Even if I choose "No profile" (meaning no stored settings are used) and create a new connection, the problem persists.